# where is the word/_rels/document.xml.rels in python docx object?

Tags: python-docx

I need the content of `word/_rels/document.xml.rels` to get the image  infomation. Does python-docx store it?

I use this:

```
>>> from docx import Document as d
>>> x=d('a.docx')
```

there seems no way to get it in `x` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python-docx and python-pptx share a common opc subpackage; this is the docx.opc subpackage.

This layer abstracts the details of the .rels files, among other things.

You can get to it using:

```
>>> document = Document()
>>> document_part = document.part
>>> rels = document_part.rels
>>> for r in rels:
...   print r.rId
'rId2'
'rId1'
'rId3'
```

*How* you use it most effectively depends on what you're trying to get at. Usually one just wants to get a related part and doesn't care about navigating the details of the packaging. For that there are these higher level methods:

- docx.opc.part.Part.part_related_by()
- docx.opc.part.Part.related_parts[rId]

In general the route from the object at hand is:

1. to the part it's contained in (often available on obj.part)
2. to the related part by use of .part_related_by() (using relationship type) or .related_parts[rId] (it's a dict).
3. back down the the API object via X_Part.main_obj e.g. DocumentPart.document

The areas in the code you might be interested in looking closer at are:

- docx/parts/
- docx/opc/part.py

Comment: in python3 seems to be `for r in rels.values()`

Comment: Ah, yes, so it is. The Relationships object inherits from dict; forgot about that :)