# How to get urls under "word/_rels/header1.xml.rels" using docx python

Tags: python, python-docx

To get the urls under `word/_rels/document.xml.rels` we can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36240552/11073769).

But I want to access the file `word/_rels/header1.xml.rels`, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
document = Document()

for section in document.sections:
    header = section.header
    rels = header.part.rels
    for r in rels:
        print(r.rId)
```